# SAS- Auto Login to a secure website , open links in it and fetch data

Tags: security, url, sas, filenames, autologin

I am a SAS programmer whose trying to automate a report for my client who creates it by fetching some data from a secure website,manually noting it down on our SAS database and then reports/validates on them. My task is to reduce the manual effort.

I tried using FILENAME URL option in Sas code to login to the page but it ends up giving me error : "SSL Error : Missing CA trust list"

So basically the task is to pass a webpage in SAS, have the code auto - login to the website through login credentials , open up links on the webpage and fetch some amounts/date from the opened link pages.

Any helpful pages to start from for me would also be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please include anonymized code (ie, no passwords or actual sites if they're not public sites) that can be used to identify your problem.

Comment: Is the remote server using a self-signed certificate?  If so, you are going to need to fetch a copy of the remote server public cert and add it to your trusted certificate store.  This action is operating system dependent so it will vary from UNIX to Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I've used successfully [CURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) tool with SAS (due some limitations in SAS 9.1)

The idea is to call `curl` via `systask command` from SAS as an external utility.
Then curl does the magic - retrieve or post/upload some content etc.

Answer (score 2):

As Vasja says CURL is the way to do it.  In the example below I've used a named pipe instead of calling curl through systask. Here's an example of the code (though it's not for the faint of heart):

```
**
** GLOLBALS
*;
%let curl_executable = d:\xxx\curl.exe;
%let maxchars        = 3000;
%let userpass        = User:Pass;


data _null_;
  ** 
  ** USE THIS VERSION IF YOU JUST HAVE A STRAIGHT URL TO RETRIEVE
  *;
  call symput ('curl_cmd', "&curl_executable -k -u &userpass %nrstr(https://www.mysite.com/index.php" );
run;


** 
** USE THIS VERSION IF YOU NEED TO PASS IN PARAMETERS TO THE URL
**
** NOTE THAT THE CARROT (^) IS REQUIRED TO MASK THE AMPERSAND WHEN 
** BEING PROCESSED THROUGHT THE COMMAND LINE PIPE. THE LOG WILL STILL COMPLAIN ABOUT
** THE MACRO VARIABLE TODT NOT BEING RESOLVED EVEN THOUGH IT IS.
*;
/*%let from=2013-01-01;*/
/*%let to  =2013-01-01;*/
/*data _null_;*/
/*  call symput ('curl_cmd', "&curl_executable -k -u &userpass %nrstr(https://www.mysite.com/index.php?FromDT=)&from^%nrstr(&)ToDT=&to" ); */
/*run;*/


**
** CONNECT TO SITE AND RETURN HTML RESULT TO A DATASET
*;
filename curl pipe "&curl_cmd" lrecl=32767;
data tmp;
  length xml $&maxchars;

  infile curl truncover end=eof;
  input @1 xml $&maxchars..;

  /*
  ** SAFETY CHECK 1 - TEST FOR TRUNCATION. LINE SHOULD NOT BE > 32K.  
  ** THIS CAN BE FIXED BY PIPING THROUGH SED AND INSERTING LINE BREAKS IF NECESSARY.
  */
  if lengthn(xml) ge &maxchars then do;      
    put "ERROR: FAILED FOR &from BECAUSE XML WAS > &maxchars CHARS";
    put "OBSERVATION: " _n_;
    put xml;
    stop;
  end;

run;
filename curl clear;
```

Once you have this working and the HTML saved into your dataset you then need to parse out the results but that's a whole different question.

Comment: @RobPenridge-Thx for sample code.I tried-
Replaced curl_executable with the location where i extracted curl executable on my SAS server
Repl userpass user with username and pass with password
Passed the URL inside the STRAIGHT URL version
Onrunning,I get the following single obs in o/p dataset: /bin/ksh: /pap/jayesh/curl.exe cannote execute[Exec format error]I understand probably the executable curl.exe can't run due to it being placed in sas server.I can't place the same on my hard drive
as my SAS system can't understand that location due to me working on Client machine(Citrix Remote System).

Comment: Looks to me like you may be running curl in a Unix/Linux environment.  If this is the case, you will need to use the appropriate curl executable file which is unlikely to have a `.exe` suffix. I suggest opening a command prompt (or in your case perhaps a telnet session/command shell), and trying to run your full CURL command from the prompt.  If successful you should see the HTML for the page being returned.  This will take any SAS-related issues out of the picture and make it easier to debug.  Once you have that working, take the command and place it into your SAS code.

Comment: For example, this command when executed from the command prompt will return the HTML code for https://developers.google.com.  It's a https site, and no user/pass is required so I've removed those from the command.   `curl -k https://developers.google.com/`

Comment: So I tried running this code through Shell(PUTTY basically)

curl -k myusername:mypassword https://www5/iso.com/pcs/app/bul/bulresults,do?searchType=3

Which gives me an error 

curl: (6) Couldn't resolver host 'myusername:mypassword'
Even though if i try the google website through PUTTY it shows the html code, but not in my website's case.
Sorry for the repeated questions.Just can't seem to make this work. Thanks.

Comment: You forgot the `-u` switch before `username:password`.  Your full curl command should read `curl -k -u myusername:mypassword www5/iso.com/pcs/app/bul/bulresults,do?searchType=3`

Comment: I am at home(have access at work only) now,so i wouldn't be able to try the command. But I did try the command above on Putty earlier. It had no results and did not give the html code for it. When i did it for the google site it did have the results. Also tried the curl pipe command on SAS for google site which did work. Shouldn't this have had the same html results as well ?

Comment: I don't know.  Perhaps posting a new question specifically targeted at getting the `curl` command working against the site you require may help solve that aspect of it.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting in newer versions of SAS, there is PROC HTTP that allows you to better handle requests (GET and POST) and responses from web servers.  This is useful if the URL returns something that is not a flat file or easily read through a DATA Step.

There are explicit instructions on HTTPS here  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/64787/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p19qqqyq9te9u3n1oq8fbdta7dqt.htm

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to login to a secure site is given in [the documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000223242.htm) :

```
filename foo url 'https://www.b.com/file1.html'
     user='jones' prompt;
```

If you're having trouble with that with the error above, it's possible you have a malconfigured SAS installation or OS.  See [this reference](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/secref/62092/PDF/default/secref.pdf), in particular the SSLCERT options in section 2, for more specific details useful for your site.

Comment: Thanks Joe.  Here's my code so far  filename foo url 'website-name'  user = 'username' pass ='password';

Comment: Thanks Joe. @Joe Here's my code so far <br/> filename foo url 'websitename' <br/> user = 'username' pass = 'password'; <br/> data abc; <br/> infile foo length = len; <br/>input record $varying200. len; put record $varying200. len;<br/> run;<br/> Which gives me the error "Error:Missing CA trust list"<br/> I believe SAS installation is fine. Is there any other licence probably that might be required to access a secure URL ? Like you mentioned having 'SSLCERT'. Probably getting SSL certificate for same? But I do have access to the website , if i simply open the same webpage on IE and do the login

Comment: @vasja : Could you please post some sample cURL code to use with SAS for same? That would be very heplful. Meanwhile I'll try searching for same on google

Comment: Please post code to the OP, not to comments - it's too hard to read in comments.